# Group_concat, joining a column into a row, if other columns are equal

Tags: mysql, sql

Running the following query on my database which contains clothes gives me a [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glkPB.jpg), where I have multiple rows of the same product where the only difference is the size column.

SQL QUERY :

```
SELECT 
categories.name AS "category",
color_variant.pcode AS "code",
stock.size AS "size",
color_variant.price AS "price"

FROM 
categories, product, color_variant, stock

WHERE
categories.id = product.category_id AND
product.id = color_variant.product_id AND
color_variant.id = stock.color_variant_id 

ORDER BY 
categories.id
```

I would like to join the size rows of each product so I get something like

```
 category    code               sizes               price
  jean   1018918053   24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32   119.99
  jean   1018916407   26                           159.99
  jean   1018917373   31                           159.99
  jean   1018917354   25                           109.99
  jean   1018919115   24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32   129.99
  jean   1018913449   24,25,26,27                  109.99
```

I tried GROUP_CONCAT by replacing `stock.size AS "size",` with

`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT stock.size ORDER BY stock.size SEPARATOR ', ') AS "sizes",`

but this gives me a single line result, where every size row is joined, even if I use it as a subquery,

```
category    code                    sizes                        price
 jean    1018918053  1,105,11-12,115,2-3,23,24,25,26,27,28,2...  119.99
```

any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? or how I can solve this problem?

Comment: did you specify `group by` clause? if you don't, and use aggregate functions, then mysql is free to group however it wants to.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY categories.name, color_variant.pcode, color_variant.price` just before your `ORDER BY`

Comment: @Linger thanks that solves this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
GROUP BY categories.name, color_variant.pcode, color_variant.price
```

just before your `ORDER BY`